# Response.data how to get a single data value

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here is the code that im using to try get a single element out of the data.response of an api:

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/random/joke',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '0f787e5af5msh468814e0b585173p1cacafjsn7d774dfb44ff'
  }
};
  if(msg.content === "daddy"){
    axios.request(options).then(function (response) {

      console.log(response.data);
      let dataDad = response.body
        msg.channel.send(`${dataDad}`)
  })`
```

and here is the response that i get from the api:

```
{
  success: true,
  body: [
    {
      _id: '60dd3729df8a37528bc79b03',
      setup: 'How often do scientists check the table of elements?',
      punchline: 'Periodically',
      type: 'periodical',
      likes: [],
      author: [Object],
      approved: true,
      date: 1618108661,
      NSFW: false
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I use the "setup" from the response data in my code at msg.channel.send( "the "setup" ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, You need to do `response.data.body[0].setup` in order to get the first objects `setup` property

```
msg.channel.send(response.data.body[0].setup);
```

Answer (score 0):

`response.data.body` is an array of objects.  So, if you want to access the first object in that array, you would use `response.data.body[0]`  So, to get the `.setup` property from that object, you would use this:

```
msg.channel.send(response.data.body[0].setup);
```

That will get you the `setup` property from the first object in the `response.data.body` array.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at /home/runner/BOT-JDS/index.js:99:39
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1

Comment: this is the error i got from it, what am i doin wrong?

Comment: Isn't it `response.data.body[0]` ?

Comment: i get this when i use ; `response.data.body[0] :: [object object]

Comment: As you should @Jordydev - that object holds all of the props you're interested in

Comment: @Jordydev -- Perhaps it is `response.data.body[0].setup`.  Your question wasn't real clear on what the response was as you were doing `let dataDad = response.body` which confused me.  Anyway, I've modified my answer to show `response.data.body[0].setup`.